# Update a property asynchronous

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

When a property of my ViewModel is updated, other property is updated asynchronous.

Todo.cshtml:

```
@page "/todo"

<h1>Todo (@todos.Count(todo => !todo.IsDone))</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in todos)
    {
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" bind="@todo.IsDone" />
            <input bind="@todo.Title" />
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<input placeholder="Something todo" bind="@newTodo"/>
<button onclick="@AddTodo">Add todo</button>

@functions {
    IList<TodoItem> todos = new List<TodoItem>();


    string newTodo;
    void AddTodo()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo))
        {
            todos.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo });
            newTodo = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

TodoItem.cs:

```
public class TodoItem
{
    private bool _isDone;

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone
    {
        get => _isDone;
        set
        {
            _isDone = value;
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //Simulate work
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                //Update property
                Title = Title + " - Done";
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In synchronous (without Task.Run) this work fine, but in asynchronous the UI isn't updated.

I need explain the UI to update with `StateHasChanged()`:
https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1413

But I can't call this method in TodoItem (and I don't want TodoItem know Blazor component).

Have you a solution to update the UI?

Comment: Why not add a callback event/handler in `TodoItem` (like `IsDoneComplete`) of type `Action` that your view registers in order to call `StateHasChanged`?

Comment: Yes, I think my VM need update the view or notify the view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do the following:

1. Define an action delegate in your class:

   ```
    public event Action OnChange;
   ```
2. In this very class define a method `NotifyStateChanged()` as follows:

   ```
    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
   ```

   This method triggers the `OnChange` event. You should call this method from your logic after fulfilling  whatever task it does.
3. In your todo Component, add the `StateHasChanged` method to the event delegate used in your `TodoItem` class thus:

   ```
    @functions
    {
        protected override void OnInit()
        {
            state.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Easy answer is *"just fire `StateHasChanged();` after modify your var"*:

```
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //Simulate work
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            //Update property
            Title = Title + " - Done";
            StateHasChanged();
        });
```

Because your method is async, rewrite as:

```
        Task.Run(async () =>  //<--here async
        {
            //Simulate async work
            Task.Run( async () => {
                await Task.Run( () => {} ); //<--- await
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            });
            //Update property
            Title = Title + " - Done";
            StateHasChanged();
        });
```

To avoid anti-pattern and write clean code, your ModelView may have a public event to let know UI it has changed, just connect this event on UI to `StateHasChanged();`.

I write here the Blazor Counter sample modified to do this:

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@IncrementCount">
    Click me @s <!-- here var -->
</button>

@functions {
    int currentCount = 0;

    string s = "";

    void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //Simulate work
                Task.Run( async () => {
                    await Task.Run( () => {} );
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));}
                        );
                //Update property
                s = s + " - Done";
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited**

Call `StateHasChanged` from a thread is not more supported. Just change:

```
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Simulate work
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        //Update property
        Title = Title + " - Done";
        StateHasChanged();
    });
```

By

```
    Invoke( () =>
    {
       ...
```